# Appium Automation with iOS Simulator not working

Tags: ios, xcode, automation, appium

First I tried my following code with iOS simulator

```
   DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
   capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "iOS");
   capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "iPhone 6 Plus");
   capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "9.1");
   capabilities.setCapability("app", "/Users/Aress-QA/Desktop/PSt-forQA.ipa");
   wd = new IOSDriver(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"),capabilities);
   wd.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

It shows following error,

```
A new session could not be created. (Original error: Could not find a device to launch. You requested 'iPhone (9.1 Simulator)', but the available devices    were: ["iPad 2 (9.1) [4A9559E1-4671-41F4-A2D0-07A4B1720CB9]","iPad Air (9.1) [02745445-2332-4588-B565-010D958368AF]","iPad Air 2 (9.1) [FF4C3B92-8441-487D-A99B-E2D47A00CEFA]","iPad Pro (9.1) [D741F907-FA3C-45E0-B3B2-5552BF23B4DB]","iPad Retina (9.1) [58471281-5A59-4DFF-B940-A1DF64C2ECF2]","iPhone 4s (9.1) [0ECC93BA-1D51-4FE2-A292-C4E7ACE7C32A]","iPhone 5 (9.1) [B332319F-895B-4F73-A3BD-303958B1126B]","iPhone 5s (9.1) [2235EFFD-E873-4809-AD49-90A26F0F579C]","iPhone 6 (9.1) [34517D5C-0737-4268-867B-ADF66F8CAC96]","iPhone 6 Plus (9.1) [89E70EB8-1D82-4F8A-95DF-EA578C3BAB08]","iPhone 6s (9.1) [598E66DB-1FD2-4439-9337-1406EF8B92E7]","iPhone 6s (9.1) + Apple Watch - 38mm (2.0) [D60DDE8F-EBB9-4226-A891-FE6CD559EE49]","iPhone 6s Plus (9.1) [9BC360EE-09D2-49CF-BD3F-718955330207]","iPhone 6s Plus (9.1) + Apple Watch - 42mm (2.0) [5E51457D-3ABE-4406-ACB3-8AEC579854C1]"]) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
```

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

`iPhone (9.1 Simulator)` =/= `iPhone 5 (9.1)`

Try to match the device name. And I would suggest to add `UDID` parameter. 
E.g. `capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.UDID, "2235EFFD-E873-4809-AD49-90A26F0F579C")`

Comment: Thanks. Just tried, however it's still not working. I used the UDID. Can you please help by pasting the exact code?

Comment: I do not run my code on emulators - I do not know. Maybe the simulator must be launched in advance?

Comment: Ok. I tried to launch the simulator prior to launching appium and the code. It still does not work. I tried the code with following desiredCapabilities settings on real device.


The application is launched and it crashes moments later. Can you please help?

Comment: It is anothere issue. If application launches then it means this issue is resolved.\

Comment: I have added another question with details for this.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33521913/appium-on-real-ios-devices

Comment: Simulator question is not answered yet. So I prefer to keep it in open state.

Comment: I faced similar issue. I would suggest you to try few hacks which worked for me- first- try the full name of the device - "iPhone 6 Plus (9.1)". Second hack- give a extra = in front of device name like- "=iPhone 6 Plus (9.1)". For me giving extra = worked.

Answer (score 0):

The iOS simulator requires *.app* and not *.ipa* -- if you have trouble obtaining the .app, then unzip the .ipa file and within the uncompressed folder, you'll find a .app