# Appium on real iOS devices

Tags: ios, xcode, automation, appium

I am using following desired capabilities with Appium and iPad 2

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability("udid", "ea56e8ae8e5f5235c16d5315f4cb34d81be55917");
capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "iOS");
capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "iPad 2");
capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "8.3");
capabilities.setCapability("app", "/Users/Aress-QA/Desktop/PSt-forQA.ipa");
capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "iOS");
wd = new IOSDriver(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"),capabilities);
wd.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

The application is launched and it crashes moments later, Appium console shows following error,

```
info: [debug] [INST STDERR] 2015-11-04 14:51:55.082 instruments[9690:170378] WebKit Threading Violation - initial use of WebKit from a secondary thread.
info: [debug] [INST STDERR] 2015-11-04 14:51:55.984 instruments[9690:170400] Attempting to change event horizon while disengage
info: [debug] [INST STDERR] Instruments Trace Error : Target failed to run: Permission to debug com.esct.PIt was denied. The app must be signed with a development identity (e.g. iOS Developer).
```

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app is not signed by your Apple Developer ID. You must do that in the XCode.

Example: https://discuss.appium.io/t/the-app-must-be-signed-with-a-development-identity/2653

Comment: What do you mean by 'that did not work'? I think that now you are getting different error, because I know the solution to this problem. I have experienced it and it is in the suggested post too.
Is the error really the same?

Comment: Yes the error was really the same. We tried something else and it worked. We signed the app with the development identity and enabled UIAutomation in the device which worked. Thanks a ton for your help. This appium setup with iOS is a bit tricky.